# Spring Boot JPA query for retrieve data from many to many Relationship Table

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I need to retrieve users from the users table where role_id =2. This is the relationship between entities.
[image]

Below MySQL query works perfectly.And Retrive users that role_id = 2.

```
select * from users INNER JOIN user_roles ON users.id = user_roles.user_id INNER JOIN roles ON roles.id = user_roles.role_id WHERE role_id='2';
```

But I need to do it in the spring boot application and this is the repository that implemented.

```
@Query("select usr from User usr INNER JOIN user_roles ur "+
        "ON usr.id = ur.user_id INNER JOIN Role roles " +
        "ON roles.id = ur.role_id WHERE ur.role_id='2' AND usr.department=(:depId)")
List<User> findAll(@Param("depId") Long depId);
```

But user_roles is not an entity and the above query does not work. Is there a solution or any other way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

This is the query you try to use from inside your program.

```
    SELECT usr
      FROM User usr 
INNER JOIN user_roles ur ON usr.id = ur.user_id 
INNER JOIN Role roles ON roles.id = ur.role_id 
     WHERE ur.role_id='2' 
      AND usr.department=(:depId)
```

`usr`, which you mention in your `SELECT` clause, is not a column in any of your tables. Maybe you should try `usr.*` instead to get all columns from the matching `User` table.

And, you don't need to join the `Role` table to get the `role_id`; it's in the `user_roles` table.  So, try this.

```
    SELECT usr.*
      FROM User usr 
INNER JOIN user_roles ur ON usr.id = ur.user_id 
     WHERE ur.role_id='2' 
      AND usr.department=(:depId)
```

**Pro tip** It's very important to be able to look at queries embedded in programs and reason about them. It's worth your trouble to format them carefully in your source code.

Comment: @Jones Problem not solved. `user_roles` is not an entity. It's a many to many mapped table. Here is the problem